# php javascript code to call php function from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

**Below is my textbox code**

```
<input id="society_name" onBlur="showsociety(this.value)" />
<input id="societyid" name="society"  />
```

**Below is my javascript which call addressdata.php page...**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function showsociety(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else
{  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) 
        {         
          document.getElementById("societyid").value = data[i].societyid;            
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","addressdata.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**Addressdata.php page**

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
$q = $_GET['q'];
$city = $database->getRows("SELECT SM.id AS societyid,SM.society from societymaster SM WHERE SM.society = :society", array(':society'=>"$q"));  
$info = array();
foreach($city as $row)
{
    $cID = $row['societyid'];  

    $info[] = array('societyid' => $cID);
}
echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

I need to fetch id in multiple textbox like above given ex...in my form.

So is this possible to convert all php code to function in addressdata.php and call this function only from javascript...

**FOR EX** - i need to make whole php code of addressdata.php file as it is in function and call tis with below javascript on textbox blur event..

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: on textbox blur event :)

Comment: i only need to wrap code of Addressdata.php page inside function with any name like functionaddress and call this functionaddress  function from javascript...this line xmlhttp.open("GET","addressdata.php?q="+str,true);

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to add more text input elements into your page and be able to use this whole process of showing society on each of this elements.

The problem is not converting php code into a function (which would bring nothing).

What you want is to be able to tell showsociety() function which input element should it work on.
In the easiest case you can add additional parameter to the fucntion:

```
showsociety(str, id) {...}
```

And use this ID to search for correct element on the page.

```
[...]
document.getElementById(id).value = data[i].societyid;  
[...]
```

.

```
<input id="society_name" onBlur="showsociety(this.value, this.id)" />
```

It can be done better but I think with such simple solution you should not have much problems.

Hope it helped.